# calling Expression.Call

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I have:

```
class X<t1>
{
   class Y<t2>
   {

      public Y<t2> Skip(int count)
      {
          var mi = (MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();
          var f = Expression.Call(null, mi,Expression.Constant(count));
          var x = this.Provider.CreateQuery(f);
          return something_else;
      }
   }
}
```

I get Y`1 Skip(Int32) contains generic parameters.

Can't make the method generic so i can call method.MakeGenericType

Any idea on how i can create the Expression.Call ?

I also tried :

```
var f = Expression.Call(typeof(Y<>), "Skip", new Type[] { gt }, Expression.Constant(count));
```

this time i get:

No method 'Skip' exists on type 'X`1+Y`1[t1,t2]'.

Comment: Can you please put this into a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
var f = Expression.Call(
     Expression.Constant(this), 
     "Skip", 
     Type.EmptyTypes, 
     Expression.Constant(count));
```

By the way,`Type.EmptyTypes` is equivalent to `new Type[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod.aspx), GetCurrentMethod does not fill in the generic arguments of the type(s) that own the current method.

Instead, an option is to use:

```
MethodInfo mi = typeof(X<t1>.Y<t2>).GetMethod("Skip");
Expression f = Expression.Call(null, mi, Expression.Constant(count))
```

Also, the first parameter shouldn't be `null`, but that's a separate issue.